# php newbie problem: regex

Tags: php, regex, line-breaks

i'm sorry i've already asked for this but couldn't find a solution yet :(
here's my string: (as you can see it has linebreaks)

```
Webname:    [webname]
Username:   [username]
IP:     [IP]
```

i need to read out the values inside the square brackets.
here's my code:

```
    $pattern = '/\[(.|\n)+?\]/'; // i've used the same syntax for my asp projects, always worked
    preg_match($pattern, $txt, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    echo "matches:".count($matches)."\n\n";
    foreach ($matches as $match) 
    {
        echo $match[0]."\n";
    }
```

i'm getting only 2 matches: `[webname]` and `e` (???)
i'm fiddling with this for hours now and can't find out what's wrong ..

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks more complicated than it has to be. Line breaks don't play any role here.

```
$pattern = '/\[(.+?)\]/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [webname]
            [1] => [username]
            [2] => [IP]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => webname
            [1] => username
            [2] => IP
        )

)
```

So the values would be in `$matches[1]`. If you want the values including the brackets (`$matches[0]`), you can also omit the parenthesis in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The first capture group, in your case there is only one, is in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$pattern = '/\[([^\]]+)\]/';
```

and use preg_match_all() to get all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$values = array();

foreach (explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/([^:]++):[^\s]*+(.*+)/', $line, $match)) {
        $values[$match[1]] = $match[2];
    }
}

var_dump($values);
```

Comment: Do you mean `+?` ? Or what is `++` supposed to mean?

Comment: It's a possessive quantifier. There's no backtracking so it's faster than just `+?`. You can read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.... but it seems PHP does not work well with it. E.g. if I exchange `?` with `+`, I get no match anymore. And btw, your code is missing a `)` and produces an empty array. At least on my system.... did you test your code?

Comment: @Felix thanks, should be fixed now